# react-grid-layout - How to make item animated when not draggable?

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

**Issue**

- I want to set animation on the grid item when using react-grid-layout as it was being dragged.

**Question**

- How can I make this item animated when clicking.
- I've tried to add the onDragStart flag to the Grid, however, I don't have the context of the item being clickable. (This with the default behaviour of being draggable)
- I've taken out the draggle feature and tried to add classes, but without success.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.